# How do I delete files in a sub directory that have the same name as a file in a parent directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder with the following file structure:

- Root (DIR)

  - Filename1.jpg
  - Filename2.jpg
  - Filename3.jpg
  - SubDirectory (DIR)

    - Filename1.jpg
    - Filename2.jpg
    - Filename3.jpg
    - SubDirectory2 (DIR)

      - FileName1.jpg
      - FileName2.jpg

etc.. The pattern continues n times.

How do I remove the files in the subdirectories if it exists at a higher level in the hierarchy of folders/files? So, I'm trying to get rid of the duplicate files in the subdirectories if the same file name exists in a higher level folder.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Skeleton: Loop through files in directory, for each file run through all subfolders, check if the file has the same filename, delete it. You can easily google the stuff together you need for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with just two **FOR** loops and one **IF** condition:

```
@echo off
rem Process all files in current directory and all its subdirectories.

rem For each file first check if the file still exists after processing
rem the other files before.

rem For each file still existing search for this file in its directory
rem and all its subdirectories with skipping from output of command DIR
rem the first line which is the current file to keep.

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir * /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    if exist "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%I" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do del "%%J" 2>nul
    )
)
```

**Note:** The batch file should not be deleted while executing it. This can be achieved by having it not stored in the directory tree to process at all, or have it only once in directory tree to process, or at least run the batch file occurrence at top most level of directory tree to process.

It is of course possible to specify on first **dir** for example `*.jpg *.png *.tif` instead of just `*` to process only JPEG, PNG and TIFF files and ignore all other files in directory tree.

Please use this modified version for a test run without real file deletion:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir * /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do (
    echo File: "%%I"
    if exist "%%I" (
        for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%J in ('dir "%%I" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do echo   del "%%J" 2>nul
    )
)
```

There would be less lines output when deletion of files is really done because of `if exist "%%I"` would not be always true as it is the case with this batch code.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `if /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` to suppress error messages by redirecting them from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

The redirection operator `>` must be escaped in first **FOR** command line with caret character `^` to be interpreted as literal character on processing the **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter but as redirection operator later by the separate command process executed by **FOR** in background to execute the **DIR** command line and capture its output written to handle **STDOUT** for processing by **FOR**.